# Finding an object: for-if vs NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa

Since I don't know how `NSPredicate` work, I usually confuse to choose which method should I use to find an object inside a collection (which implement `NSFastEnum` protocol, like `NSSet`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`)

I Usually compare string or primitiveValue (Like `NSInteger` or `BOOL`)

```
Method 1:
for (id testObj in self.myArray) {
    if ([testObj.testProperty isEqualToString:@"someString"]) return testObj;
}

return nil;

//////////////////////////////////////////////

Method 2:
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"testProperty == %@", @"someString"];
return [self.myArray arrayByFilterUsingPredicate:myPredicate].firstObject;
```

Which is better in performance? For 2 case: Big data vs small data. (Both match randomly).

**Also**

Could anyone explain how NSPredicate work?

**UPDATE**

So I've written a sample UnitTest to check the performance. I'm not sure about how to wrote it, so please help me to find out if something is not right in the the test file: [FunctionsStressTest.m](https://bitbucket.org/EddieMarvin/sampletool/raw/b1821486286d26ae79463be790c0097cfafc0cc4/TestTool/UnitTest/FunctionsStressTest.m)

It cause my PC run like crazy, fan so loud, hot, high CPU rates.... (even after finished / force end the test).

Comment: Most of the time, when searching a `NSArray`, you would use one of the `indexOfObject:` or `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` variant. Using `NSPredicate` is possible but that's more commonly used to pass the search settings to some external framework, e.g. a database framework, where you don't have control over the search and the search is not always a linear one.

Comment: Method 1 stops at the first "someString", method 2 tests all objects. I prefer `-[NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:]`. You can read about `NSPredicate` in the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html)